# Python: Reverse words in each paragraph of a file without changing the order of paragraph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse

I want to generate a ***text_out.txt*** file by reversing words in ***text_in.txt*** file like this:

text_in.txt has **two paragraphs** as below:

```
Hello world, I am Here.

I am eighteen years old.
```

text_out.txt should be like this:

```
Here. am I world, Hello

old. years eighteen am I
```

My code is:

```
filein = open ('text_in.txt', 'r+')

fileout = open ('text_out.txt', 'w')


data = filein.read()

array1 = data.split(' ')

array1.reverse()

out1 = " " .join(array1)

fileout.write(out1)
```

My results are `old. years eighteen am I \nHere. am I world, Hello`

Could anyone help me to solve it ? Thanks very much !

Comment: Split your text by newlines (I assume newline is a new paragraph) and reverse each line.

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
k = """Hello world, I am Here.
I am eighteen years old."""

x = k.split("\n")

x = [" ".join(i.split()[::-1]) for i in x]

k = "\n".join(x)
print(k)
```

Output:

```
Here. am I world, Hello
old. years eighteen am I
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
filein = open ('text_in.txt', 'r+')

fileout = open ('text_out.txt', 'a')

fileread = filein.readlines()

for data in fileread:

    array1 = data.split(' ')

    array1.reverse()

    out1 = " " .join(array1)

    fileout.write(out1)
```

Here, the idea is to read the contents of the file by line (data represents each line in the loop) and then reverse and write them to the file in *append* mode.

Alternatively, you can also use `filein.readline()` to read a line at a time.
Here's the output:

```
Here. am I world, Hello
old. years eighteen am I
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
filein = open ('text_in.txt', 'r+')

fileout = open ('text_out.txt', 'w')


data = filein.read()
out1 =  '' # initialise the empty variable
for each in data.split('\n'): # split at every instance of a newline character \n
  array1 = each.split(' ') # Use the same code
  array1.reverse()
  out1 += " " .join(array1)  + "\n" # add a new line to split

fileout.write(out1) # write
```

I gave comments as explanations

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are reversing the order of the paragraphs first, but you actually need to preserve the order. Also I would use a context manager (`with open(...)`) for file handling to ensure the files are opened and closed automatically.

I would do it like this:

```
with open("text_in.txt", 'r') as fin:
    read_data = fin.read().splitlines()        #read and split into list of paragraphs

with open("text_out.txt", 'w') as fout:
    for p in read_data:
        words = p.split()                      #split words (by whitespace)
        fout.write(' '.join(reversed(words)))  #reverse the words
        fout.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the String by \n and Then Reverse All the Lines one by one.

```
filein = open ('text_in.txt', 'r+')
fileout = open ('text_out.txt', 'a')

data = filein.read()
array1 = data.split('\n')

for i in array1:
    array2 = i.split(' ')
    array2.reverse()
    out1 = " " .join(array2)
    fileout.write(out1)
    #print(out1)
```